# Schedule data transfer free tool for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks

I have two MYSQL DB instances, i.e Instance 1 and Instance 2. I want to transfer data from Instance 1 to Instance 2 every week or every day as per the requirement on a scheduled basis(at 9:00 AM let's say).

How can we achieve it? Can this transfer of data be done automatically using any free tool?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think I have provided sufficient details.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html why not real time?